# Normalize 5-star rating to make rating more uniform

Tags: algorithm, optimization, statistics

I have a system where people rate different items on a scale from 0-5. The issue is, not everyone rates the same items, and the scoring is not objective. The goal is to achieve a fair comparison between items so that an item's score is not affected too much if one of the scorers is very "lenient" or "harsh." In actuality, there may be 100 items, each one scored twice, but here is an example dataset where 4 people scored 12 items, each one being scored twice:

```
| Item |  Score 1 | Score 2 |
           _____
   1       | 5 |     | 4 |
   2       | 5 |     | 3 |  C
   3       | 4 |     |_2_|
   4   A   | 5 |     | 5 |
   5       | 3 |     | 0 |
   6       |_5_|     | 3 |
   7       | 3 |     | 1 |  D
   8       | 4 |     | 1 |
   9   B   | 4 |     |_2_|
   10      | 4 |     | 3 |
   11      | 4 |     | 3 |  C
   12      |_5_|     | 4 |
```

In this table, the boxes represent a single person's set of scores. We can label the person who gave score 1 to items 1-6 person A, the one who gave score 1 to 7-12 person B, the one who gave score 2 to 1-3 and 10-12 person C, and the one who gave score 2 to to 4-9 person D.

Informally, if we assume person C was the closest to each item's objective score, we might reason as follows:

1. Person A generally gave higher scores than C on items 1-3 so he is "lenient."
2. D gave low scores to all of them except for item 4 which then must have been truly good. He gave scores generally lower than A, so his scores should be adjusted slightly upwards perhaps.
3. B gave higher scores than D, and a bit higher than C, so a bit "lenient".

Thus, we might produce adjusted scores for each item. For example, even though item 2 has a higher average score than item 9, they are probably on par considering A is generally lenient and D is generally harsh. The question is, how do we do this programmatically. I thought we might make several transformation functions which transform a raw score into an adjusted score, say `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. For example, we might have `A(5)=3.7` because when A rates an item as 5, it is really in the 3-4 range. Then, we want to minimize

```
|A(x_0a)-C(x_0c)|^2 + |D(x_1d)-A(x_1a)|^2 + |B(x_2b)-D(x_2d)|^2 + |C(x_3c)-B(x_3b)|^2
```

where `x_ip` is a vector which consists of person `p`'s ratings for items `3i+1`, `3i+2`, and `3i+3`. We might make `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` linear transformations, for example. How then do you optimize it? And is this the best way to eliminate one the harshness or leniency of scorers without throwing away their ratings?